# Is LDAP neccessay for on premises installation of exchange?

Tags: ldap, exchange-2016

I have installed Exchange 2016, it is a new installation as we have migrated from Lotus Notes. Emails come through the firewall and filtered by Kaspsersky Secure Mail Gateway before they reach our server. We do not use the Exchange Edge Server so is it necessary to have Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services installed?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to setup an [Active Directory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998561(v=exchg.160).aspx) at first (without an Active Directory you couldn´t deploy MS Exchange). Please keep noted that it isn´t a good idea to install MS Exchange on top of an Domain Controller. Microsoft also do not support that. So you need at least two different machines (Server 1 = Domain Controller; Server 2 = Microsoft Exchange Server). *Note: If you enroll in Exchange Online (a hosted MS Exchange) you do not need a local Domain Controller. This might be easier for you.*
2. You need to [setup an Exchange Server in that environment](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa998636(v=exchg.160).aspx) (for the same email domain as the Lotus Domino Servern). You do not need an Edge server to operate that construct (most features will be done by your Kaspersky Secure Mail Gateway).
3. Then you can configure the Lotus Domino Server as smarthost (pointing that to MS Exchange). Means every email he couldn´t route internally, but where he is authoritative, is send to an 3rd party server (e.g. your Exchange server). For the Exchange you need to do it via versa (point to the Domino SMTP). *[[here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597984(v=exchg.80).aspx) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_USING_A_SMART_HOST_STEPS.html) is a good starting point, its an old document but the idea behind that is the same]*

Via that way you can still have some users on Domino and move user by user. You can also keep some Domino Applications up and running and if you use the email address here (instead a notes name) the users on Exchange would still get the emails send from the Domino applications.

Answer (score 0):

To more succinctly answer your question, and to make a few key points:

AD DS is a requirement for Exchange. You stated that you've installed Exchange Server 2016, so you already have AD DS.

A separate Edge Transort server requires AD LDS. You have not deployed a separate Edge Transport server, so you do not need AD LDS.

> We do not use the Exchange Edge Server so is it necessary to have
>   Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services installed?

No, it isn't necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You need AD DS. Read the deployment guides on TechNet, starting with [Access to Active Directory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998561(v=exchg.160).aspx) to understand the configuration Exchange stores.